# VBA Find and Replace Syntax Error

Tags: vba, find-and-replace, syntax

I have a find and replace for some html tags and also replacing pipes with break characters. I need to replace pipe with Chr13 and then replace Chr13 with Chr10 as a subsequent step - below is the VBA I have, but it's bringing up a "Compile Error: Syntax Error. Anyone able to let me know the issue from the code displayed below please:

SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
        Selection.Replace What:="—", Replacement:="-", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
        Selection.Replace What:="", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
        Selection.Replace What:="", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
        Selection.Replace What:="ü", Replacement:="u", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
        Selection.Replace What:=">", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
        Selection.Replace What:="<", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
        Selection.Replace What:=";", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
        **Cells.Replace What:="|", Replacement:="" & Chr(13) & "", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False ReplaceFormat:=False Cells.Replace What:="Chr(13)", Replacement:="" & Chr(10) & "", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
        :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False**

Comment: That code is pretty unreadable. Please format it correctly, so people have a chance to understand it

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a **comma** before *ReplaceFormat:=False*